# Estoy Empezando con javascript y no me funciona un "alert" que estoy haciendo mal?

Tags: javascript

Es sobre variables locales y globales pero hice esto y no me funciona, con las globales solo se ejecuta el alert fuera de la funcion pero con las locales ni dentro ni fuera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido.  No pongas codigo como foto sino como texto.  Necesitas llamar a tu funcion para ver el resultado.

Comment: Por favor, en lugar de imágenes, copia y pega el código original en la pregunta. Gracias.

Comment: Disculpen soy nuevo en esta pagina, copio y pego el codigo y ya aqui se puede ejecutar o que mas se debe hacer?

Answer (score 2):

Te dejo este pequeño ejemplo, espero te sirva:

```js
var variableGlobal = "Hola mundo global!";

var miFuncion = function(){
  var variableLocal = "Hola mundo local";
  alert(variableLocal);
};

variableGlobal = "Hola mundo global modificada!";
alert(variableGlobal);
miFuncion();
```

Comment: Vez ,puedes dar una respuesta sin utilizar los negativos.

Comment: Gracias a todos, ya entendí que al final no habia llamado miFuncion.

Comment: Buen ejemplo!. y además con snippet.

Answer (score 0):

**Para ejecutar el alert con la variable local, debes llamar a la función:**

```
function miFuncion(){
        var variableLocal = "Hola mundo local";
        alert(variableLocal);
}

miFuncion();
```